# Batch file to move a file from a folder to another folder & create a text file in its place having the name of the moved file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I needed a batch file to which we could provide input (any file) from Windows 7 context menu option "Send to".
This batch file must then move that file to another folder, & create a text file in it's place with the same name as the moved file.

I needed this to move mp3 files from their album folder to a common folder, while keeping a track of which file belonged to what folder.

Comment: 1. I want it to move the files (that I would "Send to" it using right click context menu in Windows 7) to a folder that will be specified somewhere within the bat file itself.

Comment: 2. The bat file must then create a txt file with the same name as the moved file in the directory from which the file was moved.

Comment: @wOxxOm this is what I did

Comment: copy f:\data\%1 f:\data\>*.txt

Comment: move f:\data\*.txt f:\data\1\

Comment: but the problem is that, above 2 lines of code copies the same file, changes it's extension to txt & then moves it to the specified folder. I need it to create a text file of 0Kb not rename the same file

Comment: Don't add code to comments, instead, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31686068/edit) your question

Comment: Yes, please, and delete the comments afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first create a Batchfile with the following content:

```
@echo off
set newpath=H:/testing
set filename=%*
move %filename% %newpath%
set txtfilename=%filename:~0,-3%txt
echo.content of textfile >%txtfilename%
```

where insteadof the H:/testing you put the new path of your files,
and instead of the "content of textfile" you write what shall be in the textfiles created at the old location of the files.

it does not matter where you create the batch file, because in the next step you go to the search bar and type in shell:sendto and open the folder,
where you create a shortcut to your batchfile.

You can now send files to your batchfile over the "send to" menue,
and the batch file copies the file to the specified path and leaves a text file with the desired content where the moved file once was.

Edit: if you want to use it on files with varying number of characters in the ending, the code has to be modified to

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set newpath=H:/testing
set filename=%*
move %filename% %newpath%
set ending=%filename:*.=%
set txtfilename=!filename:%ending%=!.txt
echo.content of textfile >%txtfilename%
```

but in this case you can't have dots or file-endings in the names of your folders or leaving the textfile wont work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much hammockdude. Your code works just like I needed it to.

Comment: it was a pleasure :) can you leave the "solved the problem" mark?